# Find all occurences of a legacy package (sp) in my R package

Tags: r, function, package, legacy

I maintain an R package that partially depends on sp.
sp is now retiring, and I need to find all occurrences in the code that use it - to replace with functions from sf.

Finding those where I used `sp::` is easy, but I might have forgotten it somewhere, because roxygen2 still tries to load sp when preparing the documentation.
Is there a way of finding all occurrences of functions from a certain package in a file or package?

I appreciate your help!

I have manually printed the list of functions from sp but I do not plan to grep them all manually. There must be an easier way ...

Comment: Run  R CMD CHECK  and it'll tell you where there are undefined calls.

Answer (score 0):

**R CMD check**, as proposed by @Carl Witthoft in his comment, surely is the easiest way.

Otherwise, especially if you use RStudio, you can use the **findInFiles** package. First get all functions of **sp**:

```r
spfuncs <- ls(envir = asNamespace("sp"))
```

Then construct a regular expression which matches these function names:

```r
regex <- sprintf("(%s)", paste0(spfuncs, collapse = "|"))
```

Then, from the **R** directory, use **findInFiles** as follows:

```r
findInFiles::findInFiles("R", regex, perl = TRUE)
```

If you use RStudio, this will display all matches in the viewer pane, with pretty colors.